# asp.NET core publish Trimmed exiting with error code -532462766

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, publish

I am trying to publish my asp.net-core app via command line and use the "PublishedTrimmed" functionality.

I tried this both via

`dotnet build -c Release './project.csproj' /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile`

and
`dotnet publish -c Release './project.csproj' -o "outputPath"`

The publish profile used in the build command looks like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>1b763e24-74f7-453c-bf79-210861cd0fd7</ProjectGuid>
    <publishUrl>[redacted]</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishSingleFile>False</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishTrimmed>True</PublishTrimmed>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

To use the publish command i added the relevant code to the csproj file as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishTrimmed>True</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Sadly all tries i made resulted in the same error:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ILLink.targets(83,5): error MSB6006: "dotnet.exe" has exited with error code -532462766.

This also happens if I use built in publish button in Visual Studio 2019

I have currently only the v.3.1.101 (x64) .net-core SDK installed and it builds and publishes correctly when not using 'PublishTrimmed'

The error message isn't really helping me much, so can anyone tell me why this error occurs and how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use dynamic feature like Reflection? see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#assembly-linking): *It's important to consider that applications or frameworks (including ASP.NET Core and WPF) that use **reflection or related dynamic features**, will often **break** when trimmed. This breakage occurs because the linker doesn't know about this dynamic behavior and can't determine which framework types are required for reflection. *

Comment: @itminus I have read the docs. For my understanding i should expect run time errors when using reflection or other dynamic feature. So if I am not mistaken, it should still publish normally.

Comment: I agree. However, I've tried Reflection. Sometime it fails when I run "dotnet build".